# Problem with position delete Button to the right side of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a partial solution for aligning the delete button to the right side of `UITableViewCell`, it successfully position the button to the right, however when I click on the button it didn't response. I have to click on the left side of the `UITableViewCell` (original delete button position) only it gives response.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {

    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {             
                subview.hidden = YES;
                subview.alpha = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
}



- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
    [super didTransitionToState:state];

    if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask || state == UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {

                UIView *deleteButtonView = (UIView *)[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
                CGRect f = deleteButtonView.frame;
                f.origin.x += 220;
                deleteButtonView.frame = f;

                subview.hidden = NO;

                [UIView beginAnimations:@"anim" context:nil];
                subview.alpha = 1.0;
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Hoping for some ideas for this weird behavior.